# R: Using the segments function to plot a map of stacked lines

Tags: r, plot, segments

I have written a function that plots a number of lines along an axis, stacking them where they overlap. Below is the code, a sample table, and the image that it produces.

The plot is mostly exactly what I was looking for but for a few things (in order of importance):

1. Plotting the segments is an extremely slow process: about 1 segment every 0.5 seconds. Considering they are just lines I expected something much faster. I don't know the cause of this. I know that explicit loops can be slow in R so it might be this, or should I be plotting off-screen somehow and then pushing the plot to screen afterwards? Finding a time efficient method for plotting this kind of map is important because my tables can easily be tens of thousands of rows long.
2. I can't find any way of specifying the gap between y positions to be a fixed distance regardless of the number of Y positions. At the extreme, plotting just two segments produces a plot with the segments very far apart from each other.

Can anyone help me with either of these points (or indeed, anything else I could be doing better)?

(In this code reads == segments)

The function:

```
viewReads <- function(reads){
    # sort by start
    sorted <- reads[order(reads$start),];

    #---
    # In the first iteration we work out the y-axis
    # positions that segments should be plotted on
    # segments should be plotted on the next availible
    # y position without merging with another segment
    #---
    yread <- c(); #keeps track of the x space that is used up by segments 

    # get x axis limits
    minstart <- min(sorted$start);
    maxend <- max(sorted$end);

    # initialise yread
    yread[1] <- minstart - 1;
    ypos <- c(); #holds the y pos of the ith segment

    # for each read
    for (r in 1:nrow(sorted)){
        read <- sorted[r,];
        start <- read$start;
        placed <- FALSE;

        # iterate through yread to find the next availible
        # y pos at this x pos (start)
        y <- 1;
        while(!placed){

            if(yread[y] < start){
                ypos[r] <- y;
                yread[y] <- read$end;
                placed <- TRUE;
            } 

            # current y pos is used by another segment, increment
            y <- y + 1;
            # initialize another y pos if we're at the end of the list
            if(y > length(yread)){
                yread[y] <- minstart-1;
            }
        }
    } 

    # find the maximum y pos that is used to size up the plot
    maxy <- length(yread);
    sorted$ypos <- ypos;

    # Now we have all the information, start the plot
    plot.new();
    plot.window(xlim=c(minstart, maxend+((maxend-minstart)/10)), ylim=c(1,maxy));
    axis(3);

    #---
    # This second iteration plots the segments using the found y pos and 
    # the start and end values
    #---
    for (r in 1:nrow(sorted)){
        read <- sorted[r,];
        # colour dependent on strand type
        if(read$strand == '+'){
            color = 'blue'
         }else{
            color = 'red'
         } 
        #plot this segment!
        segments(read$start, maxy-read$ypos, read$end, maxy-read$ypos, col=color);
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
start   end strand
86  115 +
87  115 +
91  116 +
88  117 +
91  117 +
98  125 -
104 131 +
104 131 +
106 132 -
104 134 +
104 134 +
104 134 +
106 134 +
106 134 +
106 134 +
106 134 +
106 134 +
106 135 +
106 135 +
106 135 +
106 135 +
106 135 +
106 135 +
106 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
108 135 +
109 135 +
116 135 -
106 136 +
106 136 +
106 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 136 +
108 137 +
108 137 +
109 137 -
108 138 +
108 138 +
108 138 +
108 138 +
112 138 +
112 139 +
119 141 +
116 143 +
121 145 +
127 145 -
119 146 +
121 148 +
142 169 -
142 169 -
160 185 -
162 185 -
165 185 -
```

result:

[image: My graph]

Comment: Can you check your copy+paste of your function? There's a premature closing } after `placed <- TRUE`.

Comment: Oh god, something went bad in the middle. Sorry, I'll have that fixed in a minute!

Comment: Sounds like what happened to that sandwich I left in the fridge a few days ago.

Comment: Fixed! I think I must have slipped on my mouse and accidentally deleted a chunk :/

Comment: Fixed again. I was slightly off with the correction >_<

Comment: you could just prepare the arguments to `segments()` before hand, and make a single call to `segments()`, passing all arguments as vectors. This post includes an example of doing so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202998/plotting-a-rather-complex-chart-using-r-and-axis-break/9210688#9210688

Comment: What is this wizardry?? The plot now completes in the blink of an eye! Thanks, this is answer-worthy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have time for a worked-through example, but `segments()` (as well as other functions, like `polygons()`, `points()`, etc can take their arguments as vectors, such that you can do all of your drawing in a single function call. Often preparing the arguments prior to plotting (`apply()`ing or looping if necessary) can be way faster than repeated calls to these drawing functions. The answer in this post: [Plotting a rather complex chart using R and axis break()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202998/plotting-a-rather-complex-chart-using-r-and-axis-break/9210688#9210688) gives a complete example of this approach. You'll definitely be able to apply this to your situation. Good luck! (and thanks for telling me to answer)